# gradle build fail due to error: codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java

Tags: gradle

I got a gradle project which use 5.4.1 version, when build in ubuntu 22.04 with java version 18.0.2-ea, I got below error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:109)
```

I search it and someone suggest change gradle to 6.3, then I got below error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file '/media/sf_work/apps/TestApp/settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 62
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
```